# MYSQL:: Selecting rows from table without the most recent ones

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am struggling selecting rows from my table that haven't been modified with the current year. Here is an example of the query i gave up on:

```
SELECT *  FROM test_cars INNER JOIN
 (SELECT car as c, type as t FROM test_cars 
WHERE YEAR(modified_on)='2016' GROUP BY c,t) as tbl 
ON tbl.c!=car AND tbl.t!=type 
WHERE value !='' 
GROUP BY car,type
```

Comment: Yes please note that there are repetitve rows as the same car and type for previous years. I want to exclude all of them from my result. e.g car => ferrari,  type => F50 can have value set for 2016 and 2015. I want to exclude all of the ones that have been updated in 2016 select only cars and types where values have not been updated this year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT car, type 
FROM test_cars
GROUP BY car, type
HAVING sum(YEAR(modified_on) = 2016) = 0
```

Comment: Wow that actually worked ... why did i even go about joins. I very much appreciate your answer. I need to read more on the HAVING statement. Do you know how would it do against 120000 rows of data. I will mark your answer as soon as it allows me to

Comment: Using a function like `year()` can't make use of indexes. To use indexes you could try `HAVING sum(modified_on like '2016%') = 0` instead.